# SQL FOR XML AUTO with keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have two queries. This is query number 1:

```
SELECT JOB_NUMBER
                        FROM V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES
                        WHERE AREA_DESC = 'Orchard Park'
                        AND (DATE_TO_END IS NOT NULL AND DATE_TO_END >= GETDATE())
                        ORDER BY DATE_TO_END FOR XML AUTO
```

and this is the results:

```
<V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES JOB_NUMBER="ORC0023"/>
<V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES JOB_NUMBER="ORC0045"/>
```

and here is query number two:

```
SELECT ISNULL(UserDate1,BaseLineStart) AS BaseLineStart
                    FROM ScheduleTasks
                    WHERE (ScheduleID = (SELECT ScheduleID FROM Schedule WHERE Job_No = 'ORC0023'))
                    AND
               (
                        LibraryTaskID <> 203
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 204
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 210
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 211
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 214
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 215
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 218
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 219
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 224
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 227
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 230
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 231
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 232
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 233
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 234
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 235
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 236
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 237        
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 238
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 239
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 240
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 242
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 243
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 295
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 299
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 303
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 304
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 305
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 313
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 314
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 321
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 333

               )
                    ORDER BY SortOrder FOR XML AUTO
```

and here are the results:

```
<ScheduleTasks BaseLineStart="2015-09-11T08:00:00"/>
<ScheduleTasks BaseLineStart="2015-08-10T16:00:00"/>
<ScheduleTasks BaseLineStart="2015-08-11T16:00:00"/>
<ScheduleTasks BaseLineStart="2015-08-12T16:00:00"/>
<ScheduleTasks BaseLineStart="2015-08-13T16:00:00"/>
<ScheduleTasks BaseLineStart="2015-08-14T16:00:00"/>
<ScheduleTasks BaseLineStart="2015-08-14T16:00:00"/>
<ScheduleTasks BaseLineStart="2015-08-25T16:00:00"/>
<ScheduleTasks BaseLineStart="2015-07-31T16:00:00"/>
<ScheduleTasks BaseLineStart="2015-09-14T08:00:00"/>
<ScheduleTasks BaseLineStart="2015-09-14T08:00:00"/>
<ScheduleTasks BaseLineStart="2015-10-14T17:00:00"/>
<ScheduleTasks BaseLineStart="2015-10-15T08:00:00"/>
<ScheduleTasks BaseLineStart="2015-10-16T08:00:00"/>
<ScheduleTasks BaseLineStart="2015-10-19T08:00:00"/>
<ScheduleTasks BaseLineStart="2015-10-21T08:00:00"/>
<ScheduleTasks BaseLineStart="2015-10-23T08:00:00"/>
<ScheduleTasks BaseLineStart="2015-10-27T08:00:00"/>
<ScheduleTasks BaseLineStart="2015-10-28T08:00:00"/>
<ScheduleTasks BaseLineStart="2015-10-29T08:00:00"/>
<ScheduleTasks BaseLineStart="2015-11-02T08:00:00"/>
<ScheduleTasks BaseLineStart="2015-11-02T08:00:00"/>
<ScheduleTasks BaseLineStart="2015-11-04T08:00:00"/>
<ScheduleTasks BaseLineStart="2015-11-09T08:00:00"/>
<ScheduleTasks BaseLineStart="2015-11-11T08:00:00"/>
<ScheduleTasks BaseLineStart="2015-11-12T08:00:00"/>
<ScheduleTasks BaseLineStart="2015-11-23T08:00:00"/>
<ScheduleTasks BaseLineStart="2015-11-26T08:00:00"/>
<ScheduleTasks BaseLineStart="2015-11-27T08:00:00"/>
<ScheduleTasks BaseLineStart="2015-11-27T08:00:00"/>
<ScheduleTasks BaseLineStart="2015-12-01T08:00:00"/>
<ScheduleTasks BaseLineStart="2015-12-02T17:00:00"/>
<ScheduleTasks BaseLineStart="2015-12-02T17:00:00"/>
<ScheduleTasks BaseLineStart="2015-12-03T08:00:00"/>
<ScheduleTasks BaseLineStart="2015-12-03T08:00:00"/>
<ScheduleTasks BaseLineStart="2015-12-10T08:00:00"/>
<ScheduleTasks BaseLineStart="2015-12-17T08:00:00"/>
<ScheduleTasks BaseLineStart="2016-02-15T08:00:00"/>
<ScheduleTasks BaseLineStart="2016-02-15T08:00:00"/>
```

Now what I am looking to do is have a query that will combine these queries and return XML. I am looking to use the first query as the keys and have the second query as values....is what I am trying to do possible. I use each one of the keys to get the results of the second query. I hope this makes sense.

This is how I would like my XML to look like:

```
<ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringProductionCellModel5_PTf3dlv xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
<KeyValueOfstringProductionCellModel5_PTf3dlv>
<Key>ORC0023</Key>
<Value xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SiteSuperApp.Models">
<d3p1:baseStartFinishList>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish/>
<d3p1:baseLineStart/>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>25/09/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>12/12/2014</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>27/03/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>27/03/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>10/12/2014</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>10/12/2014</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>10/12/2014</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>10/12/2014</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>10/12/2014</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>10/12/2014</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>10/12/2014</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>10/12/2014</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>10/12/2014</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>10/12/2014</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>15/09/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>15/09/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>25/09/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>07/01/2016</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>15/09/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>15/09/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>15/09/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>15/09/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>30/11/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>13/06/2016</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>03/02/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>03/02/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>29/07/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>29/07/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>29/07/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>29/07/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>29/07/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>29/07/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>29/07/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>29/07/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>29/07/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>29/07/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>31/07/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>31/07/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>29/09/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>31/07/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>28/09/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>14/09/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>03/11/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>14/10/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>15/10/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>15/10/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>03/11/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>16/10/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>21/10/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>20/10/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>15/10/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>22/10/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>21/10/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>26/10/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>21/10/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>27/10/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>03/11/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>28/10/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>03/11/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>30/10/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>30/11/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>02/11/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>03/11/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>03/11/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>03/11/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>10/11/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>08/12/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>11/11/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>30/11/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>20/11/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish/>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>25/11/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>06/11/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>26/11/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>30/11/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>30/11/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>16/12/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>02/12/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>08/12/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>02/12/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>08/12/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>03/12/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>08/01/2016</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>09/12/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>18/01/2016</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>16/12/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>19/01/2016</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>17/12/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>26/01/2016</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>15/02/2016</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish/>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>22/02/2016</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish/>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>29/02/2016</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish/>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>01/03/2016</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish/>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>02/03/2016</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish/>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>08/03/2016</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish/>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>08/03/2016</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish/>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>18/03/2016</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish/>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>23/03/2016</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish/>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>30/03/2016</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish/>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>06/04/2016</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish/>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>18/04/2016</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish/>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>19/04/2016</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish/>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>24/05/2016</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish/>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>30/05/2016</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish/>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>09/06/2016</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish/>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>31/05/2016</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish/>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>01/06/2016</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish/>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>21/06/2016</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish/>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>10/06/2016</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
</d3p1:baseStartFinishList>
<d3p1:closingDate>16/06/2016</d3p1:closingDate>
<d3p1:daysOfConstruction>322</d3p1:daysOfConstruction>
<d3p1:daysToClosing>135</d3p1:daysToClosing>
<d3p1:notes/>
<d3p1:scheduleVariance>0</d3p1:scheduleVariance>
<d3p1:sortOrder>0</d3p1:sortOrder>
</Value>
</KeyValueOfstringProductionCellModel5_PTf3dlv>
<KeyValueOfstringProductionCellModel5_PTf3dlv>
<Key>ORC0045</Key>
<Value xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SiteSuperApp.Models">
<d3p1:baseStartFinishList>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish/>
<d3p1:baseLineStart/>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>24/12/2014</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>24/12/2014</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>06/04/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>06/04/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>24/12/2014</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>24/12/2014</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>24/12/2014</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>24/12/2014</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>24/12/2014</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>24/12/2014</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>24/12/2014</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>24/12/2014</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>24/12/2014</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>24/12/2014</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>20/04/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>20/04/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>15/05/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>15/05/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>21/04/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>21/04/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>21/04/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>21/04/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>10/12/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>07/07/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>05/05/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>05/05/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>23/04/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>23/04/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>23/04/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>23/04/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>23/04/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>23/04/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>23/04/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>23/04/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>13/05/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>13/05/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>13/05/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>13/05/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>13/05/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>13/05/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>01/06/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>01/06/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>01/07/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>01/07/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>05/06/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>05/06/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>01/07/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>01/07/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>10/06/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>10/06/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>05/06/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>05/06/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>15/06/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>15/06/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>15/06/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>15/06/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>17/06/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>17/06/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>31/07/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>31/07/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>31/07/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>31/07/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>24/06/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>24/06/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>22/07/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>22/07/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>23/07/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>23/07/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>31/07/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>31/07/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>02/09/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>02/09/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>31/07/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>31/07/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>02/09/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>02/09/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>17/09/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>17/09/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>07/08/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>07/08/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>17/09/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>17/09/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>23/09/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>22/09/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>26/09/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>01/10/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>01/10/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>05/10/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>15/10/2015</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>08/10/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>26/01/2016</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>15/10/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>29/01/2016</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>20/10/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish/>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>21/10/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish/>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>22/10/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish/>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>24/10/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish/>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>24/10/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>28/01/2016</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>28/10/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish/>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>31/10/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish>29/01/2016</d3p1:actualFinish>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>03/11/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish/>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>05/11/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish/>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>11/11/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish/>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>12/11/2015</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish/>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>30/05/2016</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish/>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>03/06/2016</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish/>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>13/06/2016</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish/>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>04/06/2016</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish/>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>06/06/2016</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish/>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>23/06/2016</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
<d3p1:actualFinish/>
<d3p1:baseLineStart>14/06/2016</d3p1:baseLineStart>
</d3p1:BaseStartFinishModel>
</d3p1:baseStartFinishList>
<d3p1:closingDate>23/06/2016</d3p1:closingDate>
<d3p1:daysOfConstruction>426</d3p1:daysOfConstruction>
<d3p1:daysToClosing>142</d3p1:daysToClosing>
<d3p1:notes/>
<d3p1:scheduleVariance>0</d3p1:scheduleVariance>
<d3p1:sortOrder>1</d3p1:sortOrder>
</Value>
</KeyValueOfstringProductionCellModel5_PTf3dlv>
</ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringProductionCellModel5_PTf3dlv>
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you should really use `WHERE LibraryTaskID NOT IN (203, 204, 210, etc.)` instead for readability's sake.

Comment: Could you add what you want the combined XML to look like?  Is the idea that you'd have the `<V_CON...` elements as parent elements to the `<ScheduledTask>` elements?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188276(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try something like this:

```
SELECT JOB_NUMBER AS [@JOB_NUMBER]
      ,(
        SELECT ISNULL(UserDate1,BaseLineStart) AS [@BaseLineStart]
        FROM ScheduleTasks
        WHERE (ScheduleID = (SELECT ScheduleID FROM Schedule WHERE Job_No = V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.JOB_NUMBER))
        AND LibraryTaskID NOT IN (203,204,210,211,214,215,218,219,224,227,230,231,232,233,234,235,236,237,238,239,240,242,243,295,299,303,304,305,313,314,321,333)
        ORDER BY SortOrder 
        FOR XML PATH('ScheduleTasks'),TYPE
       )    
FROM V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES
WHERE AREA_DESC = 'Orchard Park'
AND (DATE_TO_END IS NOT NULL AND DATE_TO_END >= GETDATE())
ORDER BY DATE_TO_END 
FOR XML PATH('V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES ') /*,ROOT('root')*/
```

The deactivated "ROOT('root')" at the end would give your XML a root-node. Otherwise it is not valid XML...